# Redmine: cannot start WEBrick (LoadError)

Tags: ruby, redmine, webrick

I am working on a CentOs 5.5. I have never worked with ruby or rails before, but recently I had to upgrade a  redmine 1.1.0 to version 2.3.1 following this [tutorial](http://wiki.bitnami.com/Applications/BitNami_Redmine#How_to_upgrade_Redmine.3f). The update process went smoothly, but once I try to start WEBrick to host the application, with the command

`ruby /var/www/redmine/script/server webrick -d -e production -p 8080` (port 80 is already being listened by an apache)

I get the following error:

```
/var/www/redmine/script/server:3:in `require': no such file to load -- commands/server (LoadError)
    from /var/www/redmine/script/server:3:in `<main>'
```

The contents in '/var/www/redmine/script/server' are:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../config/boot'
require 'commands/server'
```

My ruby version, which is compatible with this redmine version, is 1.9.2. I believe I have installed every required gem in my Gemfile. I don't know why ruby doesn't find this file, and so I tried replacing the last require with what I suspected was the filepath of the desired file.

```
require '/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/server.rb'
```

It didn't seem to work, though. Despite the fact the error was gone, I still got an "Service Unavailable" error from my browser.

Just for the record, the output as shown by the command 'gem env' is:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.0.5
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.2 (2011-07-09 patchlevel 290) [i686-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
     - /root/.gem/ruby/1.9.1
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
```

The output of 'gem list' is:

```
actionmailer (3.2.13, 3.2.0)
actionpack (3.2.13, 3.2.0)
activemodel (3.2.13, 3.2.0)
activerecord (3.2.13, 3.2.0)
activeresource (3.2.13, 3.2.0)
activesupport (3.2.13, 3.2.0)
arel (3.0.2)
atomic (1.1.4)
bourne (1.1.2)
builder (3.0.4, 3.0.0)
bundler (1.3.5)
capybara (2.0.3)
childprocess (0.3.9)
coderay (1.0.9)
erubis (2.7.0)
fastercsv (1.5.5)
ffi (1.9.0)
hike (1.2.3)
i18n (0.6.4, 0.6.1)
journey (1.0.4)
jquery-rails (2.0.3)
json (1.8.0)
mail (2.5.4, 2.4.4)
metaclass (0.0.1)
mime-types (1.23)
mini_portile (0.5.1)
minitest (4.7.5, 1.6.0)
mocha (0.13.3, 0.10.5)
multi_json (1.7.7)
mysql (2.8.1)
net-ldap (0.3.1)
nokogiri (1.6.0)
pg (0.11.0)
polyglot (0.3.3)
rack (1.4.5)
rack-cache (1.2)
rack-openid (1.3.1)
rack-ssl (1.3.3)
rack-test (0.6.2)
rails (3.2.13, 3.2.0)
railties (3.2.13, 3.2.0)
rake (10.1.0, 0.8.7)
rake-compiler (0.8.3)
rdoc (3.12.2, 2.5.8)
rmagick (2.13.2)
ruby-openid (2.2.3, 2.1.8, 2.1.4)
rubygems-update (2.0.5)
rubyzip (0.9.9)
selenium-webdriver (2.33.0)
shoulda (3.5.0, 3.3.2)
shoulda-context (1.0.2)
shoulda-matchers (1.4.2)
sprockets (2.2.2, 2.1.3)
sqlite3 (1.3.7)
thor (0.18.1, 0.14.6)
thread_safe (0.1.0)
tilt (1.4.1)
treetop (1.4.14)
tzinfo (0.3.37)
websocket (1.0.7)
xpath (1.0.0)
yard (0.8.6.2)
```

Would someone please give me a hint of the cause of the error or how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

If I'm not mistaken `script/server` is rails 2.x.x way to start the rails application.

If I look at your bundler, it now uses rails 3.x and the way to start it suppose to be with `rails server`

I verify this by looking into

http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/repository/show/tags/2.3.1/script

there is no `server` executable. but there is `rails` executable there

Check if thre is `rails` executable on the same folder.

if there is, you should be able to run rails with:

```
$ /var/www/redmine/script/rails server
```

Comment: Many thanks.Something might have gone wrong with uncompressing the new redmine file. After you answed, I checked the folders structures and it still was from the old redmine version. I restored the backups and went through this update ([tutorial](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineUpgrade)) wich seemed more recent and started the WEBrick the way you told me and everything worked